# Custom permission always denying access?

Tags: 7, users

In my module:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['reports'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'reports',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content', 'hr functionality')
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_permission() {
  return array(
    'hr functionality' => array(
      'title' => t('HR functionality'),
      'description' => t('Do things only HR are allowed to do.'),
    )
  );
}
```

I set HR to have "HR functionality" permissions. I logged in as a user with HR role, and I get access denied to my reports page. I tried clearing cache, etc. If I remove the "hr functionality" access argument it lets me in.

Even if I log in as admin, I get access denied.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The method I ended up writing per accepted answer:

```
function multiple_permission_callback() {
    global $user;
    $permissions = func_get_args();

    if (empty($permissions))
        return false;

    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
      if (!user_access($permission, $user)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution :) One thing that might be worth mentioning...if the function is called with no arguments it will always return `TRUE`. That might not be the best security practice. It's an easy fix though, `if (empty($permissions)) { return FALSE; }` before the loop

Comment: Good suggestion. Added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default function for the `access callback` is [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7), which has the following signature:

```
function user_access($string, $account = NULL)
```

This is the function that will receive your `access arguments`.

It only takes one permission string at a time, so the second string you're passing in is being used as the `$account` object. This will cause problems in the `user_access()` function and is probably why it's returning `FALSE` all the time.

If you want to test two permissions you could provide your own `access callback`:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['reports'] = array(
    'title' => 'Reports',
    'page callback' => 'reports',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => 'mymodule_reports_access'
  );
  return $items;
}

// Potentially accept an account object to make the function more re-usable
function mymodule_reports_access($account = NULL) {
  if (!$account) {
    global $user;
    $account = $user;
  }

  return user_access('access content', $account) && user_access('hr functionality', $account);
}
```

Comment: This not only answered my current question, but one I had last week. Thanks!